# Fullscreen operation is not working in selenium webdriver 3.x

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

Firefox Version: 52.0.2 (32-bit) 
Platform: Windows 7 
Selenium Webdriver version: 3.4.0 (Java bindings) 
Problem statement:
While trying to perform full screen operation in firefox browser then it throws UnsupportedCommandException

Test Code:

```
public class GeckoTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","<geckodriver executable>");
        FirefoxBinary binary = new FirefoxBinary(new File("firefox binary"));
        FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
        options.setBinary(binary);
        options.setLogLevel(Level.ALL);
        WebDriver browser = new FirefoxDriver(options);
        browser.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        browser.get("http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/examples/kitchensink/?classic#form-fieldtypes");
        browser.manage().window().fullscreen();
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(browser,20,3000);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//div[contains(@class,'x-form-spinner x-form-spinner-default x-form-spinner-down x-form-spinner-down-default')]")));
        Actions builder = new Actions(browser);
        builder.doubleClick(browser.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[contains(@class,'x-form-spinner x-form-spinner-default x-form-spinner-down x-form-spinner-down-default')]"))).perform();
        browser.close();
    }
}
```

EDIT: It seems this is an known issue and will be fixed in FF55 as per this [enter link description here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1189749)

Comment: From Gecko driver FireFox by default if get launched in Full Screen... I think gecko didn't implement any fullscreen method

Comment: It seems its an issue and will be implemented in FF55 as per this : https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1189749

Answer (score 2):

While you work with Selenium 3.4.x, geckodriver v0.16.1 and Mozilla Firefox 53.0, as you mentioned `when we try to perform full screen operation in Mozilla Firefox browser then it throws UnsupportedCommandException` is **`true`**. How ever there is an alternative to achieve the full screen operation in Mozilla Firefox which works perfect through sending **`F11 Keys`**. Here is the minimal code block to check full screen operation in Mozilla Firefox:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\your_directory\\geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver browser = new FirefoxDriver();
browser.get("http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/examples/kitchensink/?classic#form-fieldtypes");
browser.findElement(By.tagName("body")).sendKeys(Keys.F11);
```

Comment: sorry mate..fullscreen is a mode when you hit F11 on your browser. Maximize is different then fullscreen.

Comment: @MrunalGosar Check my updated answer please and let me know if it works for you. Thanks

Comment: hahahaha..well actually thats the workaround i m already using currently..but appreciate your efforts mate